# Duplicate a column in a table and update this column only

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a query table (from SQL Server) in excel. I want to duplicate column X and update this column only. What is best approach to do it?

I duplicated the original table and tried to join these two tables using Table.Join in M language, but getting error:

```
Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation.
```

I don't know if it would work though...

**EDIT**

Sample query table

```
day                 x2       duplicated_x2
2019-10-25          Open     Open
2019-10-26          Close    Close
2019-10-27          Close    Close
2019-10-28          Close    Close
2019-10-26          Close    Close
2019-10-27          Open     Open
2019-10-28          Open     Open
```

Clicking `Refresh` button updates whole table, but how to refresh only one column of this table, i.e. duplicated_x2?

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output

Comment: Check this link https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Thanks. Now I know how to merge tables via power query. But I also became to know that this way does allow not update a part of merged table.